# Sending data with fetch. How to include variable in body

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I use the API of a online service to send the email of a client that just made an order from my eshop. I do this using fetch in JavaScript. What i want you to help me with is how to include the variable, that has as value the email of the client, to the body of my request. The variable is `newClientMail` and the body of the request is body:

> '{"email": }'.
> body: '{"email": newClientMail}'

If I write it that way I get an internal server error status 500.

```
let newClientMail = clientEmail.replace('/', '');

fetch('https://useapi.useinbox.com/inbox/v1/contactlists/61b212ba8813690001cd5228/add', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken},
        body: '{"email": }'                                                            
        })
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        return response.json(); 
         })
        .then(function (data) {
         console.log(data);
        })
```

Comment: _"I do this using fetch in javascript."_ please share a [mcve] of this.

Comment: The example has syntax errors. May you fix them?

Comment: Never manually create your own JSON strings. Always use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks Phil JSON.stringify() did the job!!!!